# How did we disprove aether wind?

Tags: aether

We know that the universe is not vacuum. The average temperature of the universe is 3° above absolute zero. So some "aether" really exists, but that is not some gas with very low density, but stardust. (I know that aether was only concept for spreading of light in medium, but aether wind should exist.)
So why we don't calculate with [aether wind](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=aether+wind)?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment

Comment: Interstellar matter is a regular matter as we know it - atoms, electrons. Aether was a completely different concept and I don't see how the two could be related.

Answer (score 1):

I am intrigued by your question and take it to be roughly:

*there's stuff out there, so how do we know the true value of $c$ isn't "hidden" from us by this stuff: i.e. would $c$ be different if that stuff weren't there and how do we know $c$ isn't affected by this "stuff"?*

The answer is that the most striking and important feature about measurement-of-$c$ experiments is *not* the value of $c$ that they yield, but the *way $c$ transforms between inertial observers*.

As I talk about in detail [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/79892/26076), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90479/26076), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/83692/26076) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/100733/26076), if we make basic homogeneity and symmetry assumptions about the universe, then we can derive all possible relativities: a whole family of them, each family member characterised by a universal constant $c$ which has the outstanding and defining property that its value is the same for all observers, and Galilean relativity is the special limiting case as $c\to\infty$.

Once we have observed a speed with this property, this is powerful experimental evidence that our symmetry and homogeneity assumptions hold true. In other words, whatever "stuff" there may be out there, and whatever it is we observe to have this invariant $c$, be it a photon, a neutrino (almost) or a massless pink aardvark, we know that it (1) must be massless and (2) cannot be having any interaction with whatever "stuff" might be moving relative to us, because such interactions would violate the basic homogeneity and symmetry assumptions that beget the invariant $c$ in the first place. Thus, for example, because we can do a negative-result Michelson-Morley experiment here on Earth, we know that there is no optical medium: *i.e.* no hidden "stuff" (dark matter) that is skewing our results unless this hidden matter has no interaction with light.

Comment: or maybe a covariant one? The QFT vacuum is supposed to be populated but it is such that it obeys Lorenz invariance.

Comment: I know, I mean something different: In the universe is too much mass to disprove the calculation with this aether wind.

Comment: @annav Ssshhh! I actually like to think of the QFT ground states as an "aether" - but physicists get a bit homicidal towards you if you use that word! After all, they are what "spacetime" is made of (ground states, not physicists!). Now I was under the impression (i'm not a field theorist) that with a UV cutoff, the ground state is not quite Lorentz covariant (is only so if all frequencies are present), but of course would still seem LC if the cutoff frequency were fantastically high. Is this right? Anyhow, my point is that this "aether" fulfills the postulates of SR, so there are no "winds".

Comment: Everything is with respect to the state of the aether in which it exists including the rate at which the atomic clocks tick which are used to measure the speed of light. That's why the speed of light is always measured to be 'c'. When you take an atomic clock to the top of a mountain it ticks faster because the state of the aether in which it exists has changed.

Comment: @user36375 I'm a bit lost by your question, if you seem to know what I am saying above. I mean, let's agree to call the quantum ground states the "aether": I have no problem with that and I privately like that description, although you'll get a pretty tetchy reaction from many physicists if you use that word. But if you strip away the "aether" - QFT ground states, you don't have empty space, you have nothing there, because empty spacetime *is* the ground states of the quantum fields that fill it, or rather give it its very being. Empty space *is a real thing*, not a void, so if you strip it...

Comment: @user36375 ... away, the question of what $c$ would be is *meaningless* because *nothing* would exist. Does this make sense, or do I fundamentally misunderstand you? (One has to be very quick to qualify usage of "aether" as standing for a Lorentz-covariant entity, or something fantastically near thereto, otherwise you're likely to get your scone kicked in!)

Comment: @annav See my comments on "stripping the aether away" to the OP as well: does this make sense to you?; I fear I fundamentally misunderstand what the OP is getting at

Comment: I interpreted your response to be that what is amazing is that the speed of light is always determined to be 'c' and you were questioning how that could be if there is an aether. Whatever you want to label 'empty' space, it doesn't matter, what is important is realizing 'it' has mass and is displaced by the particles of matter which exist in it and move through it. An atomic clock at sea level ticks slower than an atomic clock at the top of a mountain because the pressure exerted toward and throughout the atomic clock at sea level is greater. This is why light is always determined to be 'c'.

Comment: @foggy please see my comments to user36375: I got confused as to who was the OP and thought he/she was.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_effect#Vacuum_energy _"a "field" in physics may be envisioned as if space were filled with interconnected vibrating balls and springs, and the strength of the field can be visualized as the displacement of a ball from its rest position"_. A field in physics is space filled with aether and the strength of the field is the displacement of the aether from its relativistic rest position. The aether is more displaced from its relativistic rest position at sea level than at the top of a mountain and exerts more pressure toward and through the atomic clock.

Comment: @user36375 I think we're likely talking about questions that can only be resolved by a full theory of quantum gravity. I mean, as soon as you introduce the Earth and sea level, you've got something very much other than the ground state, and the variation in clock rates can only be detected by taking an instrument/ signal around a loop in spacetime big enough for the holonomy to be nontrivial, i.e. you're dealing with a region whose curvature is breaking the symmetries of SR. If you keep yourself and all your instruments and signals in a flat region, though, you'll always measure $c$ to ...

Comment: What is referred to as the curvature of spacetime physically exists in nature as the state of displacement of the aether.

Comment: ... @user36375 be the same. I'm not disagreeing with you: I'm saying one would have to wait for fuller theories that describe the *nature* of this curvature more fundamentally, *i.e.* a full QTG. So, to ask a different question: does the "aether pressure on the atomic clock" description foretell anything falsifiable that is not foretold by straight, classical GR? (even though the latter doesn't tell us "why" beyond "the SE tensor is not nought"?) BTW I should warn I'm out of my depth and my understanding ends with the classical treatment of GTR.

Comment: Aether displaced by matter refutes many of the notions in quantum mechanics such as delayed choice and quantum eraser. http://www.quora.com/Mike-Cavedon/Posts/A-de-Broglie-is-correct-experiment

Comment: @user36375 OK you're waaaay too far beyond the end of Misner Thorne and Wheeler for me! But I think I understand where you're coming from: you're saying that the "displaced aether" notion is really the beginning of a quantum theory of gravity, or that it is at least the beginnings of asking *why* the EFE are the way they are, beyond hunches and mathematical requirements for divergenceless of both sides of the EFE to encode things like local conservation of energy.

Comment: I think a quantum theory of gravity is missing the point. ...

Comment: _"Think of waves on the surface of water. Here we can describe two entirely different things. Either we may observe how the undulatory surface forming the boundary between water and air alters in the course of time; or else-with the help of small floats, for instance - we can observe how the position of the separate particles of water alters in the course of time. If the existence of such floats for tracking the motion of the particles of a fluid were a fundamental impossibility in physics - ..."_

Comment: _" ... if, in fact nothing else whatever were observable than the shape of the space occupied by the water as it varies in time, we should have no ground for the assumption that water consists of movable particles. But all the same we could characterise it as a medium."_ - Albert Einstein

Comment: if, in fact nothing else whatever were observable than the shape of the space occupied by the aether as it varies in time, we should have no ground for the assumption that aether consists of movable particles. But all the same we could characterise it as a medium having mass which is displaced by the particles of matter which exist in it and move through it.

Comment: please see my comments to @user36375 .

Answer (score 1):

You are talking of the dust/atoms  between galaxies and galactic clusters and they are taken in consideration  when calculations are made about luminosities etc.  After all that is the way we know there exists matter in space, by the variations in expected luminosities.

[Here is a reference](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2000/DaWeiCai.shtml) with references to the various estimates of the density of atoms in space.  Mostly less than 1 atom per cubic centimeter. Not enough to create a wind, which is an emergent phase in much higher density matter.

Answer (score 1):

Many experiments such as the Michelson-Morley Experiment proved that if the "aether wind" exists it is extremely small and orders of magnitude less than it should be based on a classical aether theory.

The concept of an "aether" in fully MODERN terms in not dead. This aether would be a block universe fully 4D aether or a 3D LET type aether evolving through time. User36375 is right that on some levels modern physicists think there is an aether but again this has almost nothing in common with the classical idea.

Nothing is wrong with SR's formal derivation as it assumes consistency of the speed of light and derives such items like the Doppler Shift. It works very well in practice.

Nothing is wrong with neo-LET's derivation of all the equations of relativity either. For example the classical Doppler Shift equations are:

fms = f/(1+v/c)  and  fmo = f (1-v/c)

LET has time dilation and it uses the Einstein light clock which has a moving frame slowing down in time by b = (1-(v/c)^2)^.5. It applies time dilation asymmetrically as shown below:

A moving frame moves slower through time so its frequency emitted is lower.

fms = f b / (1+v/c)

Stationary frame moves faster through time so its frequency emitted is higher.

fmo = f (1-v/c)/b

fms = fmo = (1+v/c)^.5/(1-v/c)^.5  and likewise kmo = kms  where k is the wavenumber.

ALL observables between reference frames are the SAME.  E = h f and p = h k. M-M tried to show that kmo =/= kms (or equivalently wlmo =/= wlms). As far as any observer is concerned in either reference they both can claim to be the stationary observer OR the moving observer (a little known fact about SR is an observer can always claim they are the one moving and the other guy is stationary). I personally don't think this is a coincidence and using this same line of reasoning ALL of SR can be derived and expanded to all reference frames. Even Minkowski math and GR (as an acceptable approximation) can follow this line of reasoning.

This matches SR exactly yet two different mechanism occur. They're externally symmetric and the transverse forms (which Lorentz had trouble with early on) also are the same. SR can incorporate a preferred frame but no preferred frame needs to be referenced so we don't need one in the math. Nothing is ad hoc about this. You can start with one reference frame assume ALL particles not bound by a field (like the Higgs etc) move at c. This is just a standard old fashion medium idea EXCEPT the particles are all waves/wave packets themselves. Waves don't push through their medium they propagate. The Couder Walking Drop Experiment and ordinary quantum solids and liquids exhibit relativistic behaviors. The drops length contract and quantum systems exhibit relativistic behaviors even though they have a medium. They do this because the waves and the drop aren't like classical objects pushing through the medium. Rather they are part of the medium themselves. In fact classical motion might be an illusion replaced with propagation.

According to Quantum Field Theory (the most accurate theory known) particles are excitations of fields existing throughout space. Whether these fields are a three dimensional medium evolving through time or a fully four dimensional medium is not known. In fact with the math I showed here for all v < c (everything we can test) they are the same thing (although some LET like aether theories propose differences so they can run scientific tests NOT because they are necessary).

Classical aethers fight the Doppler Shift like something is pushing through it in a classical way like a boat through water. Lets derive the Lorentz Transform using the Doppler Shift equation I have. Lets pick a frequency Doppler Shift:

fmo = f (1-v/c)/b

Now lets say that for a give frequency f constant = observed time in the other frame. That is j f = t. This is just a light clock idea that any physicist would agree with. Look here under the Doppler Shift section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_paradox.

tmo/j =  t/j (1 - v/c)/b

tmo = t (1 - v/c)/b = (t - v/c t)/b  let's synchronize clocks for the comoving term using c t = x  or t = x/c to put it in the conventional form. Einstein also uses light to synchronize clocks (there's a reason for this that I could derive also).

tmo = (t - v/c x/c)/b = (t- v x/c^2)/b = Lorentz t Transform

tmo = tms because what we started with was equal. This incorporates all of relativity's length contraction, time dilation, and simultaneity. Notice, however, that while the observables between frames are symmetric here the reference frames are asymmetric. tmo and tms have different underlying mechanisms. However, uniform changes within a reference frame can't be detected, only observables between reference frames.

Neither neo-LET (the modern verision of LET) nor SR need to have any "aether drag." In fact I'd go far enough to say that LET only make sense if everything is wavelike (which it is according to QFT and QM). SR seems to require it also. The natural result of everything being a propagation of the same medium is relativity. Whether this medium is fully 4D or 3D evolving (but appearing 4D to internal observers) isn't known.

In either case I don't foresee any aether drag being necessary or Lorentz invariance violation. These may occur but only at insanely high energies. GR is upheld also for all but perhaps the most extreme curvatures (like inside a blackhole which we known nothing about anyways). I have many more equations but for the sake of room I'm not including it here. I like LET because it seems to force a fully wave like explanation that matches QFT explanation. SR matches LET exactly so it merges with QFT well for all but the most extreme energies (or frequencies) but GR is not fully wavelike and it does not fully match LET. Pretty close but its hard to reconcile it with GR under the most extreme conditions. But GR is expected to need modification there anyways. In any case reality is relativistic, no aether drag is needed.

Answer (score -1):

The "aether wind" was supposed to be the Earth's motion through an absolutely stationary space. The aether is not an absolutely stationary space. The aether is displaced by the particles of matter which exist in it and move through it.

> "The word 'ether' has extremely negative connotations in theoretical physics because of its past association with opposition to relativity. This is unfortunate because, stripped of these connotations, it rather nicely captures the way most physicists actually think about the vacuum. . . . Relativity actually says nothing about the existence or nonexistence of matter pervading the universe, only that any such matter must have relativistic symmetry. [..] It turns out that such matter exists. About the time relativity was becoming accepted, studies of radioactivity began showing that the empty vacuum of space had spectroscopic structure similar to that of ordinary quantum solids and fluids. Subsequent studies with large particle accelerators have now led us to understand that space is more like a piece of window glass than ideal Newtonian emptiness. It is filled with 'stuff' that is normally transparent but can be made visible by hitting it sufficiently hard to knock out a part. The modern concept of the vacuum of space, confirmed every day by experiment, is a relativistic ether. But we do not call it this because it is taboo."

- Robert B. Laughlin, Nobel Laureate in Physics, endowed chair in physics, Stanford University

> "any particle, even isolated, has to be imagined as in continuous “energetic contact” with a hidden medium ... If a hidden sub-quantum medium is assumed, knowledge of its nature would seem desirable. It certainly is of quite complex character. It could not serve as a universal reference medium, as this would be contrary to relativity theory."

- Louis de Broglie, Nobel Laureate in Physics

> "According to the general theory of relativity space without ether is unthinkable; for in such space there not only would be no propagation of light, but also no possibility of existence for standards of space and time (measuring-rods and clocks), nor therefore any space-time intervals in the physical sense."

- Albert Einstein, Nobel Laureate in Physics

The relativistic ether referred to by Laughlin is the hidden sub-quantum medium referred to by de Broglie is the ether which propagates light referred to by Einstein.

'Galactic Pile-Up May Point to Mysterious New Dark Force in the Universe'
http://www.wired.com/wiredscience/2013/01/musket-ball-dark-force/

> "The reason this is strange is that dark matter is thought to barely interact with itself. The dark matter should just coast through itself and move at the same speed as the hardly interacting galaxies. Instead, it looks like the dark matter is crashing into something — perhaps itself – and slowing down faster than the galaxies are. But this would require the dark matter to be able to interact with itself in a completely new an unexpected way, a “dark force” that affects only dark matter."

- quote from paper cited above

It's not a new force. It's the aether displaced by each of the galaxy clusters interacting analogous to the bow waves of two boats which pass by each other.

'The Milky Way's dark matter halo appears to be lopsided'
http://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3802

The Milky Way's 'dark matter halo' is lopsided due to the matter in the Milky Way moving through and displacing the aether.

'Offset between dark matter and ordinary matter: evidence from a sample of 38 lensing clusters of galaxies'
http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/1004/1004.1475v1.pdf

> "Our data strongly support the idea that the gravitational potential in clusters is mainly due to a non-baryonic fluid, and any exotic field in gravitational theory must resemble that of CDM fields very closely."

- quote from paper cited above

The offset is due to the galaxy clusters moving through the aether. The analogy is a submarine moving through the water. You are under water. Two miles away from you are many lights. Moving between you and the lights one mile away is a submarine. The submarine displaces the water. The state of displacement of the water causes the center of the lensing of the light propagating through the water to be offset from the center of the submarine itself. The offset between the center of the lensing of the light propagating through the water displaced by the submarine and the center of the submarine itself is going to remain the same as the submarine moves through the water. The submarine continually displaces different regions of the water. The state of the water connected to and neighboring the submarine remains the same as the submarine moves through the water even though it is not the same water the submarine continually displaces. This is what is occurring as the galaxy clusters move through and displace the aether.

What we have detected is the state of the aether as determined by its connections with the matter and the state of the aether in neighboring places, which is the state of displacement of the aether.

Comment: "About the time relativity was becoming accepted, studies of radioactivity began showing that the empty vacuum of space had spectroscopic structure similar to that of ordinary quantum solids and fluids." - could you please give a reference for this?

Comment: +1 although I am highly skeptical of the quote I asked you to find a reference for, I don't understand that at all.

Comment: You realize I am quoting Nobel Laureate Robert Laughlin, correct? http://books.google.com/books?id=_Le0UwlB-QAC&pg=PA158&lpg=PA158&dq=spectroscopic+structure++of+ordinary+quantum+solids+and+fluids&source=bl&ots=cftrN05L9F&sig=_n5EwpTGdRbooC8sos6hJO9bDC0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wgMQU8jaLMqZ1AHTnIHABw&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=spectroscopic%20structure%20%20of%20ordinary%20quantum%20solids%20and%20fluids&f=false

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I didn't realise the quote was the whole paragraph. Do you know how to "quote" something with the greater than sign? It shades the background so that it is clear where the quote begins and ends. Have a look at the edits I've made: roll them back if you don't like them, but I think it lowers the kind of confusion I tripped up on. It seems I had better read more of what prof Laughlin has to say.

Comment: I tried italicizing the quotes but your way is better. Thanks.

Comment: All popularized discussions, as the quote above, confuse the average Joe because they, without really wanting to, mix two frameworks, quantum mechanical and classical, without making a distinction. Confusion to both your houses even if one is quoting Nobel laureates ( who are not Popes for physics). When we are talking of quantum mechanical quantities as the QFT vacuum on which demonstrably particles  can be created or destroyed we are talking QM. Qunatum mechanical waves, interactions ets are all about PROBABILITIES , not physical mass waves or energy waves.

Comment: All discussions mixing a QFT vacuum without a quantized gravity set up are  misleading as are  these  ether discussions .  Galaxies are still General relativity, which is classical, gravity has not been quantized. How gravitons, if they exist, enhance and effect the QFT vaucuum is not a matter of drawing optical rays but will be the matter of quantum mechanical calculations which will end up with probability distributions for the effect of quantized gravity  on quantized light etc. Theory has not reached that point. all the rest is handwaving and misleading. The QFT sea is Probabilistic.

Comment: Aether has mass and is displaced by the particles of matter which exist in it and move through it. Displaced aether pushing back and exerting inward pressure toward matter is gravity. A moving particle has an associated aether displacement wave. In a double slit experiment the particle travels through a single slit and the associated wave in the aether passes through both.

Comment: This is nonsense within the mathematics of QFT. The pair productions in vacuum are virtual, virtual means off mass shell . The are just a mathematical construct that explains how sometimes we see real pairs, but the vacuum is not populated by on mass shell particles. It is the wavefuntion of particle arriving at two slits that defines the wave properties and it is a probability wave, not a mass, not an energy spatial variation. Massive aether has been disproved with the Michelson Morley experiment.

Comment: MMX looked for an absolutely stationary space the Earth moves through. The relativistic ether has mass. _"Subsequent studies with large particle accelerators have now led us to understand that space is more like a piece of window glass than ideal Newtonian emptiness. It is filled with 'stuff' that is normally transparent but can be made visible by hitting it sufficiently hard to knock out a part. The modern concept of the vacuum of space, confirmed every day by experiment, is a relativistic ether. But we do not call it this because it is taboo."_ - Robert Laughlin, Nobel Laureate in Physics.

Comment: MMX = absolutely stationary space. Relativistic ether = not an absolutely stationary space with mass.