# Relativity and energy

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light

If you are traveling close to *c*, doesn't the universe appear to be moving close to *c* relative to you?

If so, does this mean that the mass/energy of the universe approaches infinity from your frame of reference?

Does the universe have infinite mass from the frame of reference of a photon?

---

I apologize for wasting anybody's time.  I will go elsewhere until I've done sufficient research.  Thanks.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. Might be infinite no matter what speed you are going at.I thought you were going to ask if I am travelling towards you at c and you are travelling towards me at c, then how come the relative speed is still c.

Comment: What photon frame of reference?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The reference frame of $c$](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79787/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you are traveling close to c, doesn't the universe appear to be moving close to c relative to you?

Yes, but not all in line with your velocity. Some things are out to the side of your path.

> If so, does this mean that the mass/energy of the universe approaches infinity from your frame of reference?

No. Mass is an invariant quantity. The kinetic energy and momentum magnitudes of objects may be very large, but that is inconsequential unless you collide with them. The mass of an object is $$m=\dfrac{1}{c}\sqrt{E^2-p^2c^2}$$ and is independent of the relative speed of the object.  And there is a **huge** difference between being large and finite (your words "approaches infinity" and actually being infinite).  "Close to c" is not the same as "c".

> Does the universe have infinite mass from the frame of reference of a photon?

There is no reference frame which travels with a photon. This question has been answered [here.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79787/the-reference-frame-of-c)  And again, mass of an object is the same in all reference frames.

Comment: "Yes, but not all in line with your velocity. Some things are out to the side of your path."  If you are describing the universe from your frame of reference, then isn't your velocity zero?

Comment: One man's velocity is another man's rest frame. I also know that I have a velocity relative to other things in the universe. The important point is that the velocities are 3 dimensional, and not collinear.